# Independence of software elements for IEC 61508 on CPU without memory protection unit

Tags: c, standards, safety-critical

Is it possible to justify independence of software elements by IEC 61508, part 3, Annex F, such that the safety-related components can be rated SIL 2 and the non-safety components (e.g. UI, comms.) can be left unrated, and still have an overall result that is rated as SIL 2?

In particular I am interested in views on this when the safety and non-safety elements are all running on a single processor, and the processor does *not* implement any form of hardware memory protection. There are all sorts of things one could do to ensure that there is non-interference of software elements, such as ensuring data integrity, data passing is strictly controlled and verified, task scheduling is deterministic (non-safety tasks guaranteed to terminate), and so on.

Would such techniques rigorously applied be sufficient?

Comment: Overall, read IEC 61508 with a healthy bit of scepticism and critical thinking. There's some good things in those standards, but also a whole lot of bad and dumb things, some even outright dangerous. The main hazard is probably the cocksure way they introduce various terms and methods as if they were some widely recognized industry standard terms, when they barely exist at all outside the 61508 world, or when 61508 completely fails to name a single scientific/industry source for the claim.

Comment: This argument assumes the software is perfect.  Even if this is so, you may have bit flips from transient power, neutrinos, etc.  Any code overwrite anywhere could alter the 'perfect' assumption.  Is a system going to be safer that doesn't make this assumption? Some standards (aerospace?) call this safety related and safety function.  The UI/comms are safety related where as the actual thing you don't mention is the 'safety function'.  Techniques to ensure the safety function are needed, and that the safety related can never affect this.  Even an MMU does only so much; won't stop power glitch.

Answer (score 2):

If there is *any* safety-related firmware present in a MCU, then *all* of its software is safety-related. Period.

Common sense dictates that any bug anywhere in your code could cause runaway code, stack overflows, out of bounds access, spurious interrupts and so on. Not to mention bugs related to the interface between safety and non-safety related parts.

To make an argument about independence in a system where you would treat some parts of the software as less critical, you would need something like multiple cores executing code in different memory areas, without the slightest possibility to affect each other in any way. Which in turn would be a strange and needlessly complex design.

The normal approach is rather to set the same quality standard for every part of the code. Meaning that if you need to run some non-critical code in some non-verified stack or 3rd party lib, you should probably consider moving that to a separate physical chip. Keep the safety related parts as small and simple as possible.

Comment: Your response that if there is any safety-related firmware in a MCU then all is safety-related was my original belief and starting point, But Annex F does refer to techniques for elements on a single computer and techniques that do not need hardware protection.

Comment: @Vandermyer I assume that's IEC 61508:2010? I only have access to 61508:1998 right now, and there's no Annex F in it. Is there an explanation or sources in the corresponding part IEC 61508-7?

Comment: Yes @Lundin, I am referring to 2010. Checking 1998, I note that section 7.4.2.7 refers to independence between functions, but 2010 then also has a reference to Annex F. I ma not aware of anything in part 7 about this subject.

Comment: And also @Lundin must say I agree with the comments about going haywire. but also remember your comments about  artificial requirements. What I am looking to do here is to avoid these artificial requirements on some clearly defined aspects of the system that will only be used infrequently and under operator control, whilst stlll creating a safe system.

Comment: @Vandermyer It's hard to argue about something being used infrequently, from a safety point of view. You should have full test/diagnostic coverage of all code ever executed. And there should be no code present that is never executed, or can't be traced back to the requirements. Regarding operator control, you'll have to address that with the risk assessment... does a human operator make the product more dangerous or less dangerous etc. (Quite often, they make the product more dangerous.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have formed the opinion that: 1) demonstration of independence of software elements will probably be sufficient but 2)  there will be a need to discuss this with the assessing organization to ensure that they are in agreement with this. And if that fails, then well, I will just have to go for it and apply the full 61508 process to everything - and hope the project can be completed on time!

Comment: In my experience with a SIL3 system for a railway application, it is OK to exempt non-critical parts of the SW from certain portions of the catalogue of measures to be applied to all elements. In that case, it was only necessary to establish freedom of interference. @Lundin - I disagree with parts of your answer, which I find defined too sharply. As discussed in the comments, the crucial part is to provide measures to establish the safety function under error condition. Note that you don't have to *avoid* that runaway/stack overflow/... happens, you only have to proof that it will be detected.

Comment: @HelpingHand Indeed the key to designing these kind of systems is to assume that an error _will_ happen and then handle it. For example you can often map the stack so that when it overflows, it writes to memory leading to instruction traps/hardware exceptions. My personal design philosophy is to make an application which is _actually_ safe, and not just a SIL3 compliant death station. These SIL standards (61508 and 50239 etc) should be regarded as guidelines at best. SIL level means nothing else than that you have _considered safety standards_, not that your system is actually safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that doesn't have a definite answer. The answer is merely opinion based or depends on specific conditions.

If you have a company/organization that will do the assessment or certification you should ask them (*edit for clarification:*) if your approach is OK. As far as I understand the standards for the development of safety-critical devices you have to document that you considered all possible risks and how you detect or prevent the possible faults.

In a project to be certified to conform to a similar standard we put all safety-related data and code into specific memory sections and "lock" the safety-related data section by calculating a CRC after leaving the safety-related functions and check the CRC before entering again.

Additionally we check that the function to "lock" the data is called from the safety-related code section only by checking the return address. Any unexpected modification of the safety-related data will be detected, and the device will enter a safe state.

In our case this approach was sufficient to convince the people responsible for checking our software development.

**Edit** (to answer a comment)

Of course we are convinced ourselves that this solution is sufficient for the described purpose in the affected device.

This mechanism is only one part of the safety concept of the device.

The **CRC** mechanism described here is used to **protect safety-related data in RAM** against unwanted modification by non-safety functions to **ensure independence** of the safety-related functions from the non-safety functions. (It is not related to protecting the binary program in flash memory against modification. Of course we also do this using ECC flash and CRCs.)

**Another edit:**
We also check periodically that the safety-related peripheral registers are not modified unexpectedly.

We have lots of other safety measures in the hardware and software, but these are not related to the question how to justify independence of software parts without an MPU.

The device which uses the technique described here conforms to a different standard with a safety level approx. between SIL 1 and SIL 2.

Of course every user must check if this solution is sufficient for a specific device.

Comment: That CRC part sounds plain questionable. Corruption of the actual binary in flash memory is the least of your problems and should preferably be handled by ECC hardware nowadays. What if your "non-critical" code goes haywire and starts to write to hardware registers etc? Don't write code to "convince people", write code so that it is actually safe and you can sleep at night. This is exactly why IEC 61508 can be a safety hazard, people focus on passing various artificial requirements rather than to truly make the real-world product safe.

Comment: @ OP and @Lundin - I see the truth somewhere in the middle. (a) You shall not *ask* the assessors what to do, but *devise* a detailed concept for your safety function, and "ask" the assessors if they agree that this concept fulfills the standard. (b) Although safety-related software has been a well-established business for long time now, programmable safety systems are a complex terrain and with contradictions in safety standards, there are often multiple correct opinions next to each other. The question what ALARP means in detail is always subject to discussion (and negotiation).

Comment: @HelpingHand My experience of such assessors is that they typically don't have the slightest clue about safety in general and programming in particular. They tend to be pure bureaucrats who live in some artificial reality of a standard.

Comment: @HelpingHand Take one example: I once found a SIL3/PL e certified safety relay system, supposedly with supervision, redundancy, class 4 implementation yadayada. Then I shorted one of the 2 relays in the dangerous position and the system merrily carried on. It could only detect faults at start-up. Some year later I came across the assessor who had approved this system and asked him how they could let that system through - he just dodged it and claimed that the test house couldn't judge the actual technical implementation. That's SIL3 certification - a pile of papers.

Comment: @Lundin - You're right. This is why both the project team and the assessor share responsibility (and both go to jail when the desaster happened). I also experienced different auditors, but to me the process always boils down to "Either you avoid crossing certain boundaries (e.g., mixed-criticalitry software), or you must provide additional detail to establish that it is still safe.". Automation faces a special situation because the different perspectives of IEC61508 and ISO13849 confuse many engineers (and assessors). I also experienced ridiculous situations like the one you told.

Comment: @HelpingHand Except parts of 61508 do make sense and are indeed good/best practices, whereas the whole of ISO 13849-1 is a complete safety hazard. The parts about software are particularly laughable - my documentation about software ISO 13849-1 compliance is basically just one big newbie programming tutorial directed to the quacks who wrote the standard. "No, modern programming doesn't work that way because-..."

Comment: ("Modern" in the ISO 13849-1:2016 context meaning anything made after the year 1990 or so.)

Comment: @Lundin - yes. (-:   In our software group, nobody takes care about those few outdated lines. But it is the Cat.4 requirement for PLe that induces some additional system design requirements (like a virtually unchangeable always-two-channel architecture basis), that is (in some aspects) completely orthogonal to the good spirit of IEC61508.

Comment: @HelpingHand Yep iirc you can't claim PL e a safety function containing programmable logic unless you implement one of the SILs.

Comment: I see some critical notes were sent towards CRC calculations over ROM area. But is the given solution of doing CRC over RAM area valid? In fact I've thought about the same thing.

Comment: @MikkL. I can only tell *for a specific real device* I'm working on that this is a valid solution *in combination with other measures.*

Comment: @MikkL. To clarify, there is nothing wrong with using CRC as such, it's a good safety measure against things like data retention and other memory corruption. CRC is better than no CRC, of course. My argument is that putting a CRC check on your code memory does not automatically make that code in itself safe and protected, nor can it be used as an argument to hold other parts of the program to a lower standard. RAM corruption is just one of many bugs that the "non-safety related" code can cause. Stack overflow, spurious interrupts, writes to hardware registers, deadlock etc etc.

Comment: @MikkL. Regarding safety in RAM, there's another fairly complex method called "walking pattern" or "walking 1" or similar, where you cyclically test a little bit of the RAM by writing a 1 to it, then a zero, and checking if the values are still valid. Often checking surrounding cells as well. You'll have to consult the MCU manufacturer regarding how to implement it. I've only tried implementing it once and I think the complexity of pausing the program and wildly writing into RAM in a safe manner was a bigger safety hazard in itself, than RAM corruption because of hardware faults or cosmic rays